# Is a "Besserwisser" knowledgeable about the topics they give advice on?

Tags: word-usage

You suggested this as a word to describe someone who offers unsolicited advice.  When I heard of this word long ago I was told that it meant not only the offering of unsolicited advice but also that the advice was given without the *Besserwisser* actually having pertinent knowledge relating to the subject of the advice.  Do you know if this is accurate or not?

Answer (score 4):

A *Besserwisser* could be seen as a cross between a *nitpicker* and a *know-it-all*. A certain knowledge in the area covered is necessary to earn that title. Hence it is a criticism of social behaviour with the acknowledgement of a certain credibility.
With less credibility, such a person would be called a *Klugscheißer*.

A good example of both categories would be Sheldon Cooper of Big Bang Theory:
He likes to school people both in areas of his personal expertise (science, maths, physics) as well as others (social conventions, dating).

Comment: I disagree that a Klugscheißer has no credibility. I think he has more knowledge of a topic than a Besserwisser.

Comment: Hm. I was expressing my gut feeling, not a scientifically founded opinion. I would rank *Klugscheißer* as more derogative than *Besserwisser* though due to *...scheißer*. But that might also refer to the degree of social misbehaviour instead of credibility.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best translation for *Besserwisser* ist *know-it-all*. While the intention of a *Besserwisser* can be to help people (whether they want help or not), to me the definition also includes that fact that a *Besserwisser* knows something and wants everybody to know he knows something. That does not necessarily mean that he doesn't actually know what he talks about.

Answer (score 0):

No, necessarily not. Such person can have knowledge but it doesn't matter here. The negative term bases on the bad social behaviour but not the knowledge. Do not compare apples with pears.